# Analysis of hamster wheel rotational data

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

Before posting this question, I had a browse through other questions on this Stack, and this is probably going to be a walk in the park for anyone who reads it! But the description of this Stack includes data analysis and visualisation, so I hope this is in the right place!

</preapology>

I'm using a Raspberry Pi with a magnet and reed sensor to record what my hamster gets up to at night. The Pi records each rotation as follows:

```
2014-09-04 00:20:04.987819,1
2014-09-04 00:20:16.219891,2
2014-09-04 00:20:17.260086,3
2014-09-04 00:20:20.031204,4
2014-09-04 00:20:20.907755,5
...
```

It's when it comes to doing something with the data that I'd like some help with. Here's an example of a daily analysis the Pi produces:

> Hello daddy!
>
> Last night, I got on my wheel at 00:20 and got off to go to bed at
>   04:51 (with breaks of course!). My longest break away from the wheel
>   was for 26 minutes from 03:05 - 03:31.
>
> During the 4 hours and 31 minutes, I went round the wheel 11,903
>   times! As the wheel is 18cm in diameter, this means that I travelled
>   18π⋅11903/100 ≈ 6,731 metres. That's 4.18 miles!
>
> Love Biscuit x

I've also produced a simple graph of the data, which looks as follows:

[image: Chart of hamster wheel rotations vs time]

I've also thought of doing an hourly breakdown to see which times he's most active.

Given my non-existent statistical knowledge, that's all I can think of. Is there anything else I could be doing? (In terms of both analysis and visualisation). If it requires capturing additional data, that's fine.

**Edited to show the start of actigraphy tracking**

[image: Start of actigraphy tracking]

Comment: This may be off-topic but sounds like a fun project! From the number of wheel rotation, you can approximate how many calories the animal burnt. You can then couple this data with a feed container with a weight sensor to calculate the calorie in take. If calorie intake > calories spent, Biscuit is probably putting on weight.

Comment: @Andy - thanks. I guess I was a bit too exuberant with the smileys.

Comment: @Zhubarb - that's an excellent idea. Although I don't think I want to put him in a metabolic chamber to get a baseline for calories per rotation! I'll do a search online to see if there are any references for that.

Comment: +1 Fun project! The speed looks remarkably constant, but nevertheless maybe it could be nice to compute the top overnight speed (by finding the lowest rotation time, or maybe the lowest time for 10 consecutive rotations) and report it as well. Together with the average speed maybe.

Comment: Love it- though the first derivative ('rpm') seems much more interesting than the distance traveled as a cumulative number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a lab setting this is very often done to study [circadian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm) (i.e. ~24 hours long) rhythms.

If you can record the activity for long periods (say a few days) you can do some periodicity analysis.

The usual representation of this type of data is the actogram, which also allows you to see whether there are day to day differences.
In this example after day 8 the mouse was put in constant darkness and, as you can see, although the rhythm is always there, it shortens revealing what is usually called the "free-running rhythm".
Note that this picture is particularly clean. Sometimes you do have activity during the day!

[image: Actogram]

From: [Measuring Circadian and Acute Light Responses in Mice using Wheel Running Activity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3197401/) - LeGates and Altimus, JOVE 2011

This papers gives a nice introduction on how to analyse wheel-running data:

[A guideline for analyzing circadian wheel-running behavior in rodents under different lighting conditions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1190381/) - Jud et al. Biol Proced Online. 2005

You can also do some frequency analysis, for instance using chi-square periodograms.
See: [The chi square periodogram: its utility for analysis of circadian rhythms.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/566361) - Sokolove and Bushell, J Theor Biol. 1978 (sorry, behind a pay wall, but see also the refs [here](http://www.circadian.org/periodogram.html))

One thing you may do is to see whether these rhythms change during the week. For instance, I assume you wake up later (and make less noise) during weekends.
Does that affect the end of wheel running activity?
Do the rhythms change between summer and winter?

Also, if you hook up a camera to the system you can do some motion tracking. Here is [an example of "hamster tracking" using Python and OpenCV](http://derek.simkowiak.net/motion-tracking-with-python/).

Comment: Hey @nico. It's going to take me a while to go through all the links you posted, but I wanted to say thanks for a great answer! I've started the actigraphy and edited my original post to show a graph of a couple of days. (Wednesday is shorter than the others because it was the first day and I didn't start recording until about 00:20; when I have plenty of data points, I'll remove it). As the days are getting shorter, it'll be interesting to see whether the lines start to shift to the left.

Answer (score 5):

What questions would you ask about the data?

- How long did the hamster spend on the wheel last night?
- Was it longer or shorter than the night before that?
- Is there any day per week that the hamster runs longer on the wheel? Eg does a hamster have a week day or weekend day %^)?
- How long does the hamster stay on the wheel in a continuous stretch, on average?
- Does different type of food affect the time the hamster spends on the wheel?
- Do my activities change the hamster's wheel behaviour?

All of these would suggest different types of plots. Aggregate time on wheel by day, plot over days.

See http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/hofmann-unwin-cook.pdf for how to plot data in different ways to explore different things, answer different questions. One plot is almost never enough.

Comment: +1 I really appreciate this, your first answer here, for its focus on the questions rather than the technology.  Thank you for joining us!